# EXTJS - How to bind save click of a form.Panel to my Model

Tags: extjs, model

```
Ext.define("Imobfusion.data.User",{
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields:[
        {name: "name",type: "string"},
        {name: "email",type: "email"},
        {name: "password",type: "password"}
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: '/user/read',
            create: '/user/create',
            update: '/user/update',
            destroy: '/user/destroy'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }        
    }
});
```

Have a simplist way to bind model with form like this?:

```
Ext.define('Imobfusion.window.UserForm', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        model: 'Imobfusion.data.User' //This is my need (XD)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`loadRecord()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-loadRecord) method witch loads an `Ext.data.Model` into this form by calling `setValues` with the record data and on save use [`updateRecord()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-updateRecord) witch persists the values in this form into the passed Ext.data.Model object in a beginEdit/endEdit block. If the record is not specified, it will attempt to update (if it exists) the record provided to loadRecord. or just use [`getRecord()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getRecord) and [`getValues()`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getValues) to update the record.

Answer (score 0):

You can load record to form. After editing (record.set()) the record data is sent to the server. You need an example?